# angular 5 save form data in modal class in an array and show it in table

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, dependency-injection, model

I want to save form data in model class and show it in table. 
once form submited. I pushing the data into class by this.user.addOject() method. but the array always showing last submitted form values only.

after mentioned edits by sajeet: I got StaticInjectorError

***this.user.getUsers();
the array data is showing the last submitted form data only.
{userid: 1, firstName: "ffrere", lastName: "trtr", mobile: "355667676878", accsprofile: Array(1)}***

this is my model class

```
export interface IUser {
    userid: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    mobile: string;
    accsprofile: string[];
}
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    user: IUser;
    userlist: Array<object> = [];

    constructor() {}

    addOject(): void {
       this.user = user;
       this.userlist.push(this.user);
     }

    getUsers(): any {
        return this.userlist;
    }
}
```

**UserDiaologue.component.ts**

```
export class UserdialogueComponent implements OnInit {

  userList: IUser[];      
  user: Usermodel;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private user: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  openDialog() {

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig(); 
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UserformComponent, dialogConfig);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {    
      const userData = {
        userid: result.data.userid,
        firstName: result.data.userid,
        lastName: result.data.userid,
        mobile: result.data.userid,
        accsprofile: result.data.userid
      };           
      this.user.addOject(userData);         
      console.log(this.user.getUsers()); // always showing last inserted record.         
    });
  }
}
```

***the array is showing only the last entered form data.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a service instead of class,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class userService {
  user: IUser;
  userlist: Array<object> = [];

  constructor(user: IUser) {

   }

    addOject(): void {
       this.userlist.push(this.user);
     }

    getUsers(): any {
        return this.userlist;
    }

}
```

and inject this particular service in your component, rest should work fine

Comment: I got error --"typeof Usermodel' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'"I --I changed UserModel to UserService and inected into UserdialogueComponent constructor like this: constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private user: Usermodel) . and called the add oject.

Comment: user is of type UserModel

Comment: First problem occured is I have to use angular 5. So, Injector with providedIn root is not working. and in userservice model I removed params in constructor and changed it to addOject(user: IUser): void {
        this.user = user;
        this.userlist.push(this.user);
    }. and it is still not working. user of type userservice. not user model. I will edit the question again.

Comment: Sajeetharan, I edited the code. I am getting StaticInjectorError. please help me out. tq

Comment: you need to add the service under module.ts

Comment: Sajeetharan, You made my day. If I am girl I should love you. Thanks for your time and prompt help.. I added providers: [Usermodel] in module.